# how to wait for starting thread to have executed init code

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I'm having trouble synchronizing a master thread to a recently started child thread.

What I want to do is:

- master thread creates a new child thread and blocks
- child thread starts and initializes (might take some time)
- once the child thread is initialized, the main thread continues (and the two threads run in parallel)

My first attempt was something like:

```
  typedef struct threaddata_ {
    int running;
  } threaddata_t;

  void*child_thread(void*arg) {
    threaddata_t*x=(threaddata_t)arg;
    /* ... INITIALIZE ... */
    x->running=1; /* signal that we are running */

    /* CHILD THREAD BODY */

    return 0;
  }

  void start_thread(void) {
    threaddata_t*x=(threaddata_t*)malloc(sizeof(threaddata_t));
    x->running=0;
    int result=pthread_create(&threadid, 0, child_thread, &running);
    while(!x->running) usleep(100); /* wait till child is initialized */

    /* MAIN THREAD BODY */
  }
```

Now I didn't like this at all, because it forces the main thread to sleep for probably a longer period than necessary.
So I did a 2nd attempt, using mutexes&conditions

```
  typedef struct threaddata_ {
    pthread_mutex_t x_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  x_cond;
  } threaddata_t;

  void*child_thread(void*arg) {
    threaddata_t*x=(threaddata_t)arg;
    /* ... INITIALIZE ... */

    pthread_cond_signal(&x->x_cond); /* signal that we are running */

    /* CHILD THREAD BODY */

    return 0;
  }

  void start_thread(void) {
    threaddata_t*x=(threaddata_t*)malloc(sizeof(threaddata_t));
    pthread_mutex_init(&x->x_mutex, 0);
    pthread_cond_init (&x->x_cond , 0);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&x->x_mutex);
    int result=pthread_create(&threadid, 0, child_thread, &running);
    if(!result)pthread_cond_wait(&x->x_cond, &x->x_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&x->x_mutex);

    /* MAIN THREAD BODY */
  }
```

This seemed more sane than the first attempt (using proper signals rather than rolling my own wait loop), until I discovered, that this includes a race condition:
      If the child thread has finished the initialization fast enough (before the main thread waits for the condition), it will deadlock the main thread.

I guess that my case is not so uncommon, so there must be a really easy solution, but I cannot see it right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proper way of condvar/mutex pair usage:

```
bool initialised = false;
mutex mt;
convar cv;

void *thread_proc(void *)
{
   ...
   mt.lock();
   initialised = true;
   cv.signal();
   mt.unlock();
}

int main()
{
   ...
   mt.lock();
   while(!initialised) cv.wait(mt);
   mt.unlock();
}
```

This algorithm avoids any possible races. You can use any complex condition modified when mutex locked (instead of the simple !initialised).

Comment: +1: also for adding protection against spurious wake-ups to the `while()` loop.

Comment: Note that this is exactly like a combination of the OP's two approaches (with the `usleep()` in the first approach being replaced by the `pthread_cond_wait()`).

Comment: Note that running flag in the first approach isn't protected by mutex.

Comment: Well, yes, it's a *correct* combination of the OPs two approaches ;)

Answer (score 2):

The correct tool for that are `sem_t`. The `main` thread would initialize them with `0` and wait until it receives a token from the newly launched thread.

BTW your mutex/cond solution has a race condition because the child thread is not locking the mutex.

Comment: i'll look into mutexes but in after posting i also noticed the cause for the race-condition. do i understand correctly that it is enough to enclose the call to pthread_cond_signal() with a lock/unlock of my mutex (that is locked before calling pthread_create)? i think it should and there is no need for a "while(!initialized)wait()" loop as proposed by @dmitry-poroh

Comment: it seems that sem_t is not available on some w32-implementations of pthreads (at least the implementation i'm bound to use). the code is supposed to run on a variety of systems, including w32, which pretty much excludes that solution, though it indeed seems to be the most elegant one.

Comment: yes, since you take the mutex before launching the thread, the thread can only lock the mutex when the main thread is inside the wait. A pity that there are still pthread implementations around that don't have `sem_t`.

Comment: Windows has its own semaphore implementation.  You can write a wrapper around it that uses pthread semaphores if available and Windows semaphores if not.

Comment: +1. Probably, rendezvous using sem_t is more suited to this problem than a barrier or a condvar/mutex combo.

Answer (score 2):

A barrier should do the trick nicely. Since you mention the need for support on Win32 in comments, barriers are supported on the latest Win32 pthreads, so you shouldn't have to write your own wrapper to get some portability between Win32 and *nix.

Something like:

```
typedef struct threaddata_ {
    pthread_barrier_t* pbarrier;
} threaddata_t;

void* child_thread(void*arg) {
    threaddata_t*x=(threaddata_t*)arg;
    /* ... INITIALIZE ... */

    int result = pthread_barrier_wait(x->pbarrier);

    /* CHILD THREAD BODY */

    return 0;
}

void start_thread(void) {
    pthread_barrier_t barrier;
    int result = pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, 2);

    threaddata_t*x=(threaddata_t*)malloc(sizeof(threaddata_t));
    x->pbarrier = &barrier;

    int result=pthread_create(&threadid, 0, child_thread, &x);

    result = pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    /* child has reached the barrier */

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);  /* note: the child thread should not use    */
                                        /* the barrier pointer after it returns from*/
                                        /* pthread_barrier_wait()                   */


    /* MAIN THREAD BODY */
}
```

The drawback to this solution is that it may needlessly blocks the child thread momentarily. If that's a problem, the [condition variable solution mentioned by Dmitry Poroh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11472124/12711) is the way to go.